# Arbitrary command line arguments in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I want to allow arbitrary command line arguments.  If the user provides me with a command line that looks like this

`myscript.py --a valueofa --b valueofb posarg1 posarg2`

I know that `a` was passed with `valueofa`, `b` passed with `valueofb` and that I have these last two positional arguments.

I've always used optparse, for which you specify exactly which arguments to look for.  But I want the user to be able to define arbitrary "macros" from the command line.  Surely there's a python module that does it more elegantly than anything I'd write.  What is?

Comment: The analogy I had in mind was using gcc like `-Dthismacro=macrovalue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885161/how-can-i-get-optparses-optionparser-to-ignore-invalid-arguments). If you have to support this, you'll need to write your own option parser =(.

Answer (score 4):

`arbitrary_args.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def parse_args_any(args):
    pos = []
    named = {}
    key = None
    for arg in args:
        if key:
            if arg.startswith('--'):
                named[key] = True
                key = arg[2:]
            else:
                named[key] = arg
                key = None
        elif arg.startswith('--'):
            key = arg[2:]
        else:
            pos.append(arg)
    if key:
        named[key] = True
    return (pos, named)


def main(argv):
    print(parse_args_any(argv))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

`$./arbitrary_args.py cmd posarg1 posarg2 --foo --bar baz posarg3 --quux`:

> (['cmd', 'posarg1', 'posarg2', 'posarg3'], {'foo': True, 'bar': 'baz', 'quux': True})

`argparse_arbitrary.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-D', action='append', )
D = {L[0]:L[1] for L in [s.split('=') for s in parser.parse_args().D]}
print(D)
```

`$./argparse_arbitrary.py -Ddrink=coffee -Dsnack=peanut`

> {'snack': 'peanut', 'drink': 'coffee'}

Comment: I think this should be selected as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Will [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) do what you want?  It was recently added to the standard library.  Specifically, you might want to look at [this section](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing) of the documentation.

Comment: I think it doesn't: "The parse_args method attempts to give errors whenever the user has clearly made a mistake" means that undefined arguments will cause errors.  In fact, I think this is deliberate behaviour -- it's not often that you want to allow e.g. spelling mistakes.